# Is there any update on trial server that can prevent an app to work properly with fullsync?

Tags: convertigo

It looks like trial server was updated with the brand new 7.6 convertigo version.
.
My app (convertigo 7.5.6) on trial doesn't work anymore because (it looks like) convertigo is looking for couchDB server on 127.0.0.1 local ip adress.

Do I have to upgrade my app into 7.6 version ? Or what sould I do to make it work as-is on trial ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Our CouchDB server was out.
Now it is up again, can you confirm this is ok for you ?

Comment: @alexsolex could you please validate the answer and vote up please ?